# What is the default unit of Zonal Geometry Table and how to change it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I want to summarize the area of each region group of my result. I sort them out based on the value (score that I granted them). Now I need to pick the best 15% land from the targeted area based on the score.

My method now is to list the values of all the region groups and I add up the area of first 10-15 group maybe until it fills the goal. However the info about the land I have is in acre, which is numerically smaller and easier to calculate. And the result of Zonal Geometry Table is largely and clearly not sharing the same unit as shown below

[image: Result of the Zonal Geometry Table]

What is the unit of the AREA column and is there anyway to change that?

Comment: It should be based on the linear unit of the coordinate system that the data's in. Based on the number sizes, meters? So area will be in square meters.

Comment: Thank you. It is feet and the math checks out. You are right. So I guess it can be hard, if not impossible to change without changing the coordinate system?

Comment: Use the field calculator to either change the values in place, or to a new field (set to double). The sq feet to acres conversion is divide by 43560.